# Adding an element to JSON returned from a map loop with a final Promise.all

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-firestore, retool

I'm using Retool and looking up records in a Firestore table by a Document ID.

The below code works great and returns an array of JSON objects. However it does not have the appIDs[?] used in the lookup. How can I add the appIDs ('id1','id3', or 'id2') as an additional element to the matching JSON object in the array? The order of the returned array of JSON objects is not necessarily the same order as the appIDs array.

```
var appIDs = ['id1','id3','id2'];

var metadatas = appIDs.map(row => {
  return qTile_description_v1.trigger({
    additionalScope: {
      appID: row
    }
  });
});

return Promise.all(metadatas.map(p => p.catch(error => null)));
```

Comment: *The order of the returned array of JSON objects is not necessarily the same order as the appIDs array.* Really? It should be, in which case zipping the two arrays together should be easy

Comment: @CertainPerformance I was told that there are cases where they would not be, but I may have been misinformed.

Comment: Indeed, there are no such cases. (If there are, the engine the code is running on is broken)

Comment: I stand better informed then. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Answer in comments.
Apparently the answer is easy since my statement that the order returned may not be the same as the order of the keys in the array is false. The order will be the same, so problem solved.